# How do I install Komodo Edit on Ubuntu Xenial & Beaver?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, software-installation, komodo-edit

I am interested in installing the latest open source release of Komodo Edit to assist me with programming on either of my Ubuntu distributions.  I viewed the official site (by ActiveState) and found a .tar download for Linux.  Can I **receive** some **guidance for** the **installation** on both Ubuntu 16.04 + 18.04?

Also, are there **other methods** that exist to install Komodo Edit other than by the usage of the .tar file?

Thanks in advance, comrades!